# How can I save currency other than NSDecimalNumber?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I am using the [Realm.io](http://realm.io/) database for iOS. I am creating a [RLMObject](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.86.3/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#) and it only supports `NSInteger, CGFloat, int, long, float, and double` for numbers but not `NSDecimalNumber`. I thought about using a `double` but saw that it has rounding errors, less than a `float`, but it still has them. What would be the best way to go about storing currency?

Comment: You could always use character format.  I've never known a DB to not support character format.  Otherwise you can store dollar amounts as integers multiplied by 100, or carefully surround float/double numbers with appropriate rounding algorithms.

Comment: +1 for storing currency as integers multiplied by 100. This will allow you to do numerical comparison queries that storing strings won't provide.

Comment: @Sirens I just accepted it although I would probably opt for the integer method mentioned above nowadays simply because it would allow mathematical operations in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your options is to use an NSString for storage. A basic outline of what you would need to do would be:

1. Get the string "14.10" from your `NSDecimalNumber`
2. Store it in Realm

---

When you want to get it back, you would pull the object so you have your string back again and then you would need to run `+ (NSDecimalNumber *)decimalNumberWithString:(NSString *)numericString` which would lead you back to your value

Comment: But you can't sum this values on-the-fly... bad solution.